# Generate XML File From Generated Object

Tags: c#, .net, xml, namespaces, xsd

I started with three (3) XSD files provided from an external party (one XSD links to the other two).  I used the xsd.exe tool to generate a .NET object by running the following command: `xsd.exe mof-simpleTypes.xsd mof-isp.xsd esf-submission.xsd /c` and it generated a single CS file with a handful of partial objects.

I've created an `XmlSerializerNamespaces` object and fill with the namespaces required (two directly used in the provided sample XML file as well as two others that don't appear to be referenced).  I have successfully generated an XML file using the following method:

```
private XmlDocument ConvertEsfToXml(ESFSubmissionType type)
{
    var xml = new XmlDocument();
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(type.GetType());
    string result;
    using (var writer = new Utf8StringWriter())  //override of StringWriter to force UTF-8
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, type, _namespaces);  //_namespaces object holds all 4 namespaces
        result = writer.ToString();
    }
    xml.LoadXml(result);
    return xml;
}
```

My problem that I'm facing is in the generated CS file, one of the objects has a property (another generated partial object) that is of type `XmlElement`.  I have successfully built the object in code, and I'm having an issue converting the object to an `XmlElement`.  The questions and answers I have found here on SO say convert it to an `XmlDocument` first and then take the `DocumentElement` property.  This works, however the returned XML has namespaces embedded in the element as follows:

```
<esf:ESFSubmission xmlns:isp="http://www.for.gov.bc.ca/schema/isp" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:esf="http://www.for.gov.bc.ca/schema/esf">
  <esf:submissionMetadata>
    <esf:emailAddress>test@test.com</esf:emailAddress>
    <esf:telephoneNumber>1234567890</esf:telephoneNumber>
  </esf:submissionMetadata>
  <esf:submissionContent>
    <isp:ISPSubmission xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:esf="http://www.for.gov.bc.ca/schema/esf" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:isp="http://www.for.gov.bc.ca/schema/isp">
      <isp:ISPMillReport>
        <isp:reportMonth>12</isp:reportMonth>
        <isp:reportYear>2014</isp:reportYear>
        <isp:reportComment>comment</isp:reportComment>
        <isp:ISPLumberDetail>
          <isp:species>FI</isp:species>
```

Note: this is just a partial of the generated XML file (for illustration purposes).

As you can see, each XML node is prefixed with the namespace variable.  My question is: how can I do this in code?  Is my approach sound and if so, then how do NOT include the namespaces in the `ISPSubmission` node OR if there is a better way to approach this problem that I overlooked, please provide insight.  My desired outcome is to have all namespace definitions at the top of the document (their appropriate location) and not on the sub elements - as well as maintain the namespace variables on each element as illustrated above.

**EDIT** (after reggaeguitar's comment)

Here is the sample XML document I was provided

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<esf:ESFSubmission xmlns:esf="http://www.for.gov.bc.ca/schema/esf"
  xmlns:isp="http://www.for.gov.bc.ca/schema/isp" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.for.gov.bc.ca/schema/esf esf-submission.xsd
                        http://www.for.gov.bc.ca/schema/isp mof-isp.xsd">
    <esf:submissionMetadata>
        <esf:emailAddress>mailto:eric.murphy@cgi.com</esf:emailAddress>
        <esf:telephoneNumber>6044445555</esf:telephoneNumber>
    </esf:submissionMetadata>
    <esf:submissionContent>
        <isp:ISPSubmission>
            <isp:ISPMillReport>
                <isp:reportMonth>06</isp:reportMonth>
                <isp:reportYear>2014</isp:reportYear>
                <isp:reportComment>Up to 4000 characters is permitted for notes in this element.</isp:reportComment>
                <isp:ISPLumberDetail>
                    <isp:species>FI</isp:species>
                    <isp:lumberGrade>EC</isp:lumberGrade>
                    <isp:gradeDescription/>
                    <isp:size>2x4</isp:size>
                    <isp:finishType/>
                    <isp:length>10</isp:length>
                    <isp:thickWidthUom>IN</isp:thickWidthUom>
                    <isp:volumeUnitOfMeasure>MBM</isp:volumeUnitOfMeasure>
                    <isp:volume>11543.987</isp:volume>
                    <isp:amount>1467893.98</isp:amount>
                    <isp:invoiceNumber>837261</isp:invoiceNumber>
                </isp:ISPLumberDetail>
                <isp:ISPLumberDetail>
                    <isp:species>CE</isp:species>
                    <isp:lumberGrade/>
                    <isp:gradeDescription/>
                    <isp:size/>
                    <isp:finishType>D</isp:finishType>
                    <isp:thickness>40</isp:thickness>
                    <isp:width>100</isp:width>
                    <isp:thickWidthUom>MM</isp:thickWidthUom>
                    <isp:volumeUnitOfMeasure>MBM</isp:volumeUnitOfMeasure>
                    <isp:volume>9743.987</isp:volume>
                    <isp:amount>1247893.98</isp:amount>
                    <isp:invoiceNumber/>
                </isp:ISPLumberDetail>
                <isp:ISPChipDetail>
                    <isp:species>CE</isp:species>
                    <isp:unitOfMeasure>BDT</isp:unitOfMeasure>
                    <isp:wholeLogInd>N</isp:wholeLogInd>
                    <isp:destinationCode>FBCO</isp:destinationCode>
                    <isp:destinationDescription/>
                    <isp:volume>563</isp:volume>
                    <isp:amount>54463</isp:amount>
                    <isp:invoiceNumber>12345679</isp:invoiceNumber>
                </isp:ISPChipDetail>
            </isp:ISPMillReport>
            <isp:ISPSubmitter>
                <isp:millNumber>103</isp:millNumber>
                <isp:contactName>Dave Marotto</isp:contactName>
                <isp:contactEmail>eric.murphy@cgi.com</isp:contactEmail>
                <isp:contactPhone>2507775555</isp:contactPhone>
                <isp:contactPhoneExtension>1234</isp:contactPhoneExtension>
            </isp:ISPSubmitter>
        </isp:ISPSubmission>
    </esf:submissionContent>
</esf:ESFSubmission>
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure but maybe look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnamespacemanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d6730bwt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem by doing the whole thing in code and not even using the `xsd.exe` to generate a .NET object.